# Spring keep build and external config values for map and merge it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have spring boot app with config defined in application.yaml
And I have properties file annotated with ConfigurationProperties. In that prop model I have Map<String, Integer>
When I have build my jar and trying to run it I have the values from application.yaml in my repo AND in addition new values in application.yaml that I leave near jar file. So spring merge 2 configs. How I can fully prioritize external config file?
Thanks

Comment: you can use environemnt varaible `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` or `spring.config.location` more details check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files)

Answer (score 0):

In general you can refer to an explict location by using the environment property `spring.config.location`. If you want to merge different property files, you should use the prefix 'optional'.

In your case:

```
java -jar yourproject.jar \
     --spring.config.location=optional:./application.yaml
```

Hint: `spring.config.location` can be used multiple times.

Comment: My app successful found my config file and use it. But merged it with config in my repo. I have my local config with A and B values and my prod config with B and C values. And with it my production jar uses all values from both configs. A B and C

Comment: Just for clarification: You have different environments, e.g. test and prod. Each of them uses the same set of properties, but with different values. Everything clear so far? That's common sense. There are 2 different possibilities to solve this. 1) working with profiles, or 2) working with merged properties.